# I want to make a transparent BACKGROUND frame with my python app (WxPython)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, transparent

I've always wanted to make a app that's transparent, I love how it looks. I tried to make on of my apps transparent with the `SetTransparent(alpha)`, but I bumped into a big problem.

Yes it makes my app transparent (^。^), but it makes EVERYTHING transparent (=。=).

I have no idea how to fix this problem. Hours of research didn't really help out.

What I meant by background is, nothing else but the literary background of the app. not the button, not the status bar, not the title, just the background. for instance if i wanted the background alpha being 250 i want the buttons to look like there floating.

Example:

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
win=wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Simple', size=(800,600), style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
win.SetTransparent(200)

win.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @agf,any help? I know there must be a way to just make the background transparent.

Comment: I don't really know `wxpython`, I just edited your post to make it easier for other people to read. If you edit it and add some more information, it will bump it to the top of the "active" lists, and more people will see it.

Comment: Are you looking to mask things with an alpha channel?  I.e. have a custom frame shape?  Or are you looking to make parts of it transparent?  What do you mean by "background" is key.

Comment: @chow What I meant by background is, nothing else but the literary background of the app. not the button, not the status bar, not the title, just the background. for instance if i wanted the background alpha being 250 i want the buttons to look like there floating.